# How do I validate JSON data in a form

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a HTML form that i am filling out with JSON data once a bit of that data is called, there are also 2 sets of data in my JSON file.

I am trying to make my error alert appear when the string of data (*in this circumstance it is a reference number*) is incorrect however, everytime I type in one of the reference numbers, the error message appears because the other one isnt being called, can anyone help me with this?

Here is my JQuery:

```js
    $("#clickme").click(function () {
        $.getJSON("insurance.json", function (obj) {
            $.each(obj, function (key, value) {
                //Makes sure Search matches a reference number
                if ($("#search").val() == value.InsuranceReferanceNumber) {
                    $(".hide").addClass("show");
                    $(".hide").removeClass("hide");
                    $(".ins").hide();
                    // Inputs values into form
                    $("#firstname").val(value.Firstname);
                    $("#lastname").val(value.Lastname);
                    $("#address").val(value.Address);
                    $("#phone").val(value.PhoneNumber);
                    $("#dob").val(value.DOB);
                    $("#email").val(value.Email);
                    $("#carmanf").val(value.CarManufacturer);
                    $("#model").val(value.CarModel);
                    $("#year").val(value.Year);
                    $("#fuel").val(value.FuelType);
                    $("#engine").val(value.EngineSize);
                    $("#cover").val(value.TypeofCover);
                    $("#bonus").val(value.NoClaimsBonus);
                    $("#paid").val(value.Paid);
                    $("#amount").val(value.Amount);
                }
                else {
                    alert("Error");
                }
                
            });
        });
    });
```

Here is the JSON file, it is filled with false data.

```js
[{
        
            "InsuranceReferanceNumber": "CAR123"
            , "Firstname": "Jerry"
            , "Lastname": "Ford"
            , "Address": "1 Brick Lane"
            , "PhoneNumber": "077123456"
            , "DOB": "12/08/1976"
            , "Email": "jerry.ford@mail.com"
            , "CarManufacturer": "Audi"
            , "CarModel": "R8"
            , "Year": 2017
            , "FuelType": "Diesel"
            , "EngineSize": 5.2
            , "TypeofCover": "Third Party "
            , "NoClaimsBonus": "3 Years"
            , "Paid": "Annually"
            , "Amount": 1800
        }
 
    , {
    
            "InsuranceReferanceNumber": "CAR456"
            , "Firstname": "Danny"
            , "Lastname": "Beach"
            , "Address": "23 Oaklands Dr"
            , "PhoneNumber": "077654321"
            , "DOB": "09/11/1996"
            , "Email": "danny.beach@mail.com"
            , "CarManufacturer": "Vauxhall"
            , "CarModel": "Corsa"
            , "Year": 2011
            , "FuelType": "Petrol"
            , "EngineSize": 1.2
            , "TypeofCover": "Comprehensive"
            , "NoClaimsBonus": "2 Years"
            , "Paid": "Monthly"
            , "Amount": 800
        }
 
]
```

Comment: Is the `insurance.json` publicly available?

Comment: Apologies, I have just inserted it into the post :)

Comment: The way you are iterating is wrong. $.each is getting an array "[]" and not as an json object {}. If you pass array you will get index and item as argument to callback , something like this $.each(function(index,item){}), now once you have an item you can do comparision as $(#search).val() == item. InsuranceReferanceNumber.

Comment: Thanks for that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if I correctly understood your question, but I''ll try to help. You have logical operation inside '$.each' cycle and when

```
$("#search").val() == value.InsuranceReferanceNumber
```

is incorrect, your code fires alert. However, this code will show alert almost every time actually, so I think you have  to change your code with this:

```js
    $("#clickme").click(function () {
        $.getJSON("insurance.json", function (obj) {
            var found=false;
            $.each(obj, function (key, value) {
                //Makes sure Search matches a reference number
                if ($("#search").val() == value.InsuranceReferanceNumber) {
                    $(".hide").addClass("show");
                    $(".hide").removeClass("hide");
                    $(".ins").hide();
                    // Inputs values into form
                    $("#firstname").val(value.Firstname);
                    $("#lastname").val(value.Lastname);
                    $("#address").val(value.Address);
                    $("#phone").val(value.PhoneNumber);
                    $("#dob").val(value.DOB);
                    $("#email").val(value.Email);
                    $("#carmanf").val(value.CarManufacturer);
                    $("#model").val(value.CarModel);
                    $("#year").val(value.Year);
                    $("#fuel").val(value.FuelType);
                    $("#engine").val(value.EngineSize);
                    $("#cover").val(value.TypeofCover);
                    $("#bonus").val(value.NoClaimsBonus);
                    $("#paid").val(value.Paid);
                    $("#amount").val(value.Amount);
                    found=true;
                    return false;
                }
                
                
            });
            if(!found)
               alert("Error");
                
        });
    });
```